# How to call to a function, with a string

Tags: javascript, .net, html

i am creating a string from all the headlines of a table, that making a checkbox to each headline, and its should hide the col if its unchecked and show if its checked.
the function put all the checkbox in a div.

i am calling the function when the page is loaded (onload in the body)

this is my function:

```
function getFirstRow(table) {
    var table = document.getElementById(table);
    var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
    var cells = row.getElementsByTagName('th');
    var str = "";
    for (var i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        str += "<input type='checkbox' onclick='hideOrShowCol('TreesTable', "+i+", this);' checked='checked' />" + cells[i].innerHTML + " ";
    }
    document.getElementById("hideAndShow").innerHTML = str;
}
```

and this is the hide/show function:

```
function hideOrShowCol(table, col, e) {
    alert(e.checked);
    var ifToShow = "";
    if (e.checked)
        ifToShow = "table-cell";
    else
        ifToShow = "none";
    var getTable = document.getElementById(table);
    var tds = getTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        tds[i].childNodes[col].style.display = ifToShow;
    }
}
```

so the problem is that it is not calling to the function when i am creating the check boxes with the first function, but when i am writing directly in the html its works fine, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="hideOrShowCol('TreesTable', 2, this);" checked="checked" />
```

some one know what its can be?? i tried everything...
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"<input type='checkbox' onclick='hideOrShowCol('TreesTable', "+i+", this);' checked='checked' />"` is invalid because of the single quotes areound 'TreesTable' nested inside the single quote for the onclick.

Try changing to `"<input type='checkbox' onclick='hideOrShowCol(\"TreesTable\", "+i+", this);' checked='checked' />"`

Comment: Even better. Don't use inline JavaScript at all :)

Answer (score 0):

try closing over 'i' and passing it to an anonymous self-invoking function:

```
for (var i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    (function(indx) {
        str += "<input type='checkbox' onclick='hideOrShowCol('TreesTable', "+indx+", this);' checked='checked' />" + cells[indx].innerHTML + " ";
    })(i);
}
```